# Plot multiple bar plots with three groups while dividing two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have this dummy df:

```
data = {'numerator_en':[11, 113, 53],
             'denominator_en':[91, 982, 298],
             'numerator_fr':[6, 232, 58],
             'denominator_fr':[63, 1278, 389],
             'numerator_th':[14, 652, 231],
             'denominator_th':[416, 3835, 1437],
             }

dummy_df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['numeric', 'text', 'both'])
```

Which looks like that:
[image]

The goal is create such a plot:
[image]

Note that  english, french and thai should just have different colors - nothing fancy as in the image.

Hereby the y axis equals numerator_xx / denominator_xx for all languages divided into numeric, text and both. 
For instance, numeric would be row numeric: numerator_en/denominator_en and numerator_fr/denominator_fr and so on...

English = `_en`
French = `_fr`
Thai = `_th`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a MultiIndex with [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split) then divide `numerator` by `denominator`:

```
dummy_df.columns = dummy_df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
dummy_df = dummy_df['numerator'] / dummy_df['denominator']
```

`dummy_df`:

```
               en        fr        th
both     0.177852  0.149100  0.160752
numeric  0.120879  0.095238  0.033654
text     0.115071  0.181534  0.170013
```

Then [`plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) as normal:

```
dummy_df.plot(kind='bar', rot=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = {'numerator_en': [11, 113, 53],
        'denominator_en': [91, 982, 298],
        'numerator_fr': [6, 232, 58],
        'denominator_fr': [63, 1278, 389],
        'numerator_th': [14, 652, 231],
        'denominator_th': [416, 3835, 1437]}

dummy_df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['numeric', 'text', 'both'])

dummy_df.columns = dummy_df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
dummy_df = dummy_df['numerator'] / dummy_df['denominator']

dummy_df.plot(kind='bar', rot=0)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use groupby with `axis=1` to make groups based on `en`/`fr`/`th`.
Then you can evaluate the `numerator/denominator` for each group.
Finally, you can use `.plot(kind ='bar')` to plot the bar graph.

```
(
    df.groupby(df.columns.map(lambda x: x.split('_')[1]), axis=1)
    .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:, 0].div(x.iloc[:, 1]))
    .plot(kind='bar')
)
```

##### OUTPUT:

[image]